# Is there an advantage to cover all bands of GNSS constellations when selecting an antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, gps, gnss

I am shopping for shark-style (or aerodynamic low-profile) antennas to make the most of my GNSS receiver (a Septentrio Mosaic X5). Is there any advantage to cover all bands (i.e. ~1.1GHz to 1.6GHz) of all constellations, compared to covering one band of every constellation (e.g. 1.5 to 1.6GHz)? Antennas which cover the whole spectrum and also meet my other requirements are difficult to find.

Comment: Of course covering more satellites can improve your fixes. You might even be able to avoid the ones NATO are jamming this week https://msi.nga.mil/queryResults?publications/broadcast-warn?navArea=A&msgNumber=2362&msgYear=2021&output=html

Comment: I am not saying covering more satellites, I am saying covering more bands - unless each satellite within one constellation operates in a different band?

Comment: If there is a specific situation where one of the bands is getting badly affected, there maybe some use of other bands. I've heard that pine cones affect a certain frequency when they are of a certain length.

Comment: Well, it is a matter of pros vs cons.